# Copying image in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an image control in a Word UserForm and a button which opens a dialog box to let the user select an image. If I want to copy this image to another document, how do I do it via code?

Here's the code to select the image via the button:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select Photo"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg", 1

    If .Show = -1 Then
        filetoinsert = .SelectedItems(1)
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        Next vrtSelectedItem            
            Me.myImage.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
    End If

   End With

   Set fd = Nothing

End Sub

At the bottom of this form, I have another button that will copy this photo to another document. Here's what i've tried so far:

Private Sub cmdTransferPhoto_Click()

'Copy and Paste photo on "NextDoc" document. On the this document, I have a Picture Content Control called "Picture" where i plan to paste the copied image 

Set Picture = NextDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Picture").Item(1)
Picture.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
Me.myImage.Picture, linktofile:=False, savewithdocument:=True
        
End Sub

When I click, the cmdTransferPhoto button, I get this error 

Run-time error '5152'
This is not a valid file name.
Try one or more of the following:
* Check the path to make sure it was type correctly.
*Select a file from the list of files and folders.

Ideas are welcome! Thanks.
```

Comment: Please post your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you could have discovered from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture), and should have noticed from the Intellisense, `.InlineShapes.AddPicture` takes `FileName`, datatype string, as the required argument. As you are attempting to pass an image (which will be a rather poor quality bitmap) into this argument it quite naturally fails.

You already obtained the filename which you used to load the picture into the image control, so why not use it?

```
Picture.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=filetoinsert, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
```

Comment: Where does image control store the filename (and/or path) to the image?

Comment: "Where does image control store the filename (and/or path) to the image?" - it doesn't. You obtained the path and filename when the user selected the image, so store it in a variable with appropriate scope and you can reuse it.

Comment: Ok will try that. Thanks for the suggestion.